# Oracle timestamp ignores Time.use_zone in Rails 4.2.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, ruby-on-rails-4

We recently upgraded our rails application from rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3 to rails 4.2.7 and ruby 2.3.1. But I ran in to an issue with the Oracle timestamp field. It ignores the time zone set by Time.use_zone. But the date field still works as in the previous version.

```
CREATE TABLE TESTS
( ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL 
, TIMESTAMP_FIELD TIMESTAMP 
, DATE_FIELD DATE 
, CONSTRAINT TEST_PK PRIMARY KEY 
( ID )
 ENABLE 
);
```

rails c (in our rails 4.2 application)

```
> Test.create(id: 1, timestamp_field: Time.now, date_field: Time.now)
#<Test id: "1", timestamp_field: "2016-08-18 17:06:51", date_field: "2016-08-18 15:06:51">

> puts Test.find_by_id(1).timestamp_field
2016-08-18 17:06:51 +0200

>  puts Test.find_by_id(1).date_field
2016-08-18 17:06:51 +0200

> x = Proc.new { puts Test.find_by_id(1).timestamp_field }
> Time.use_zone('Adelaide', &x)
2016-08-18 17:06:51 +0200

> x = Proc.new { puts Test.find_by_id(1).date_field }
> Time.use_zone('Adelaide', &x)
2016-08-19 00:36:51 +0930
```

In the rails 3.2 the timestamp_field did get affected by the Time.use_zone and showed the same time as date_field when using the Time.use_zone.

**Update**

application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Amsterdam'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

**Update**

```
> Test.find_by_id(1).timestamp_field.class
Time
> Test.find_by_id(1).date_field.class
ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

So, the issue is caused by a different implementation of these objects. Strange it's a Time object and not an ActiveSupport object

Comment: Neither `DATE` nor `TIMESTAMP` data type contains any time zone information. The problem must be somewhere at your application layer

Comment: What happens if you first test date_field before timestamp_field? Does it yield same result?